# Samba user share with bindfs --enable-lock-fowarding --enable-ioctl --multithreaded

Tags: linux, locking, samba

I tried to use bindfs to share the files by Samba.

```
bindfs --enable-lock-fowarding --enable-ioctl --multithreaded /data/share1 /home/user1/share1
bindfs --enable-lock-fowarding --enable-ioctl --multithreaded /data/share1 /home/user2/share1
```

In linux filesystem, flock is works well because of --enable-lock-fowarding.

I shared it by Samba.
smb.cnf

```
[homes]
path = /home/%S
```

but when user1 and user2 use same file(sample1.xlsx), file locking never work because internal path becomes different one.

*file path for user1

```
/home/user1/share1/sample.xlsx
```

*file path for user2

```
/home/user2/share1/sample.xlsx
```

Is there good way to enable lock  on Samba?

Answer (score 0):

[homes] is a special Samba share and does not take a 'path' parameter, try a different share.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).